# Characteristic of a ring whose non-units form an additive subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with unity $e$. Suppose non unit elements of $R$ form a subgroup of $R$ under addition. Show that the characteristic of $R$ is either $0$ or a power of a prime.

Not able to do this. Any clue, please?

Comment: Suppose $R$ is a unital ring whose characteristic is positive and divisible by (at least) two distinct primes. Show that then $R$ contains two non-units whose sum is a unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $ne=0$ and $ke\neq 0$ for $1\le k\le n-1$. If $p,q$ are different primes and $pq$ divides $n$ then $px+qy=1$ for some integers $x,y$. We have that $q$ does not divide $x$ and $p$ does not divide $y$. Then $pxe$ and $qye$ are divisors of $0$, and hence are not units but $pxe+qye$ is an unit.